# Not able to retrieve info.plist data by -pathForResource method?

Tags: ios, plist, nsbundle

In my application I am not able to get the plist using the below code. I am using Xcode 4.5
and here is my code for retrieving plist,

```
    NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSDictionary *theDictionary;
    NSString *commonDictionaryPath;
    if (commonDictionaryPath = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"newfonts-Info" ofType:@"plist"])
    {
        theDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:commonDictionaryPath];
    }
```

**Note:-** If I try to retrieve a text or xml file then the above code works fine.

Answer (score 2):

To get the Info plist as a dictionary, you can just do:

```
NSDictionary *theDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
```

Comment: Your method isn't necessarily wrong, just more complex than required.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
```

Calling `infoDictionary` on any bundle instance will return something (thought it may only contain private keys).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 SArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


 NSString* fooPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"newfonts-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSLog(fooPath);
 contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:fooPath];
 NSLog(@"%@",contentArray);
```

or this can also works with NSDictionary

```
 NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"newfonts-Info" ofType:@"plist"];

 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

 NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

i hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the answer by self

I just open the documents directory and open the application.app file and got to see that the plist file which is shown as `application-Info.plist` in the bundle is seen just as `Info.plist`

so I changed the above code and and retrieve the dictionary

```
NSString *commonDictionaryPath;
commonDictionaryPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *info=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:commonDictionaryPath];
NSLog(@"path %@",commonDictionaryPath);
```